# How to use scanf after Wrong input format (the garbage value)?

Tags: c, integer, printf, scanf, garbage

I'm trying to get two integer inputs one by one. But when I use wrong input format like char/string/floating-point for the first input, the program ends without getting an input for the second one.

Although there are some ways to resolve this problem like using isdigit() with char input, I want to use scanf_s and "%d" for this problem.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {

    unsigned int id = 0;

    printf("Enter ID\n");
    scanf_s("%d", &id);

    printf("%d\n", id);

    unsigned int id2 = 0;

    printf("Enter ID2\n");
    scanf_s("%d", &id2);

    printf("%d\n", id2);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Test the return value of scanf_s to know if it was successful or not, and do the correct action (asking again or continuing).

Answer (score 0):

Like `scanf`, `scanf_s` returns the number of successfully assigned fields. So simply use:

```
if(scanf_s("%d", &id) != 1) {
    // Handle error
}
```

You could do it like this:

```
int r;
do {
    printf("Enter ID\n");
    r = scanf_s("%d", &id);
} while(r!=1)
```